# How to add title and border around SQL query in php

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to add a title and border around my SQL query in php. At the moment it displays the new note to be added and displays the previous added notes underneath.

Please see image:
[image]

And here is my code I have thus far:

```
 <div><?php $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','tasks_db');
            $fetchnotes = mysqli_query($con,"select * from `notes` where ticket_id = '$id'");
            while($fn = mysqli_fetch_array($fetchnotes)){
            echo '<div>' .$fn['note']. '</div>' ;}?></div>
```

So what I am trying to achieve is to display the "note added by: xxxx" and then a border around the notes

Thanks

Comment: can you share the fields names in the notes table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div><?php $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','tasks_db');
            $fetchnotes = mysqli_query($con,"select * from `notes` where ticket_id = '$id'");
            while($fn = mysqli_fetch_array($fetchnotes)){
            echo '<div style="border: 1px solid black;>' .$fn['note']. ' Note added by: '.$fn['author'].'</div>' ;}?></div>
```

replace $fn['author'] with the correct field name